# How can i create mutiple nginx ingress controller in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I have 2 namespaces in my kubernetes cluster, one called `first-nginx` and the other called `second-nginx`. I am using the chart [**ingress-nginx**](https://ingress-nginx%20https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx).. **NOT** the **stable/nginx-ingress** as that is now deprecated.

I am attemtping to install multiple nginx controllers, because i need them to be exposed by an already created static ip in GKE. I have successfully installed my first chart in the first-nginx namespace like this

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace first-nginx --set ingress-class="nginx-devices --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP={first-IP-address}"
```

I am now attempting to do the same with in the second namespace like this

```
helm install nginx-ingress-2 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace second-nginx --set ingress-class="nginx-devices --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP={second-IP-address}"
```

However i get an error as shown below.

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.
> Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace ""
> exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid
> ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key
> "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "nginx-ingress-2": current
> value is "nginx-ingress"; annotation validation error: key
> "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "second-nginx": current
> value is "first-nginx"

How do i solve this ? This seems to work when i use the stable/nginx-ingress chart where i can do something like this `helm install nginx-ingress-devices stable/nginx-ingress --namespace second-nginx --set controller.ingressClass="nginx-devices"`

How do i acheive the same thing with the **ingress-nginx**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define additional `controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue` for the second ingress-nginx, so that when an ingress resource refer to this class, it knows which controller to engage.

```
helm install nginx-ingress-devices ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx  \
  --namespace second-nginx \
  --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=second-nginx \
  --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="k8s.io/second-nginx" \
  --set controller.ingressClassResource.enabled=true \
  --set controller.ingressClassByName=true
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `controller.ingressClassResource.name` to set different ingress class names for them